# why is this node.js application throwing ENOENT error?

Tags: node.js

```
res.sendFile(path.join(
__dirname, '..', 'client', 'views', 'index.html'));
```

this line of code generates a 404 error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/[username]/workspace/client/views/index.html'`

for the following folder structure

workspace/

⠀⠀webapp/

⠀⠀⠀⠀client/

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀views/

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀index.html

⠀⠀⠀⠀server/

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀routes/

⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀index.js

Comment: Notice how `webapp` is missing between `workspace` and `client` in the error message. Which file contains this code? (I assume it’s not server/routes/index.js, because [__dirname]/../client/ is server/client/ there.)

Comment: @Ry- it is that file

Comment: What does `console.log(__dirname)` show in the same spot, and do you have a compile step of some kind (e.g. Babel)?

Answer (score 0):

seems the path "/Users/[username]/workspace/client/views/index.html'" has a missing '⠀webapp/' in between workspace and client.

By default the server looks for the files which are present in views folder with its default configuration settings in Express, If you want to change it you can use the method set() to redefine express's default settings.

```
 var express = require('express');
 var path = require('path');
 var app = express();

 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/ViewDirectorypath'));
```